# Concatenate ruby hash's keys

Tags: ruby

I have a hash. How could I concatenate the keys so that `current_hash.keys` result looks something like this: `"key1 key2 key3 key4"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_hash.keys` returns an array, you can join the array elements by using `join()` in ruby, try this out

```
current_hash.keys.join(" ")
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do `current_hash.keys.join(' ')` for example -

```
  hsh = {key1: "dsfsd",key2: "sfdsdf"}

  hsh.keys.join(' ')  # "key1 key2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the keys in the question were in sorted order, so perhaps

```
current_hash.keys.sort.join(" ")
```